# Converting non-standard Subversion repository to git

Tags: svn, git, migrate

I have a repository whose layout is like this:

```
    trunk/
        projectA
        projectB
    branches/
        projectA-1.0
        projectB-1.0
    tags/
        projectA-1.0.1
        projectB-1.0.1
```

I want to convert them to separate git repositories with the trunk/projectA as the top-level directory and all it's branches as git branches.

Whenever I try to specify a `git svn init` like `git svn init -T trunk/projectA -b branches -t tags http://svn.example.com`, the follow-up `git svn fetch` fails mysteriously on different revisions.  Sometimes it gets all the way to 200, sometimes it stops.

My current thinking is that I should create a git repository that mirrors the whole subversion repository as a single entity with subdirectories for each project.  Then I would use `git-filter-branch` to rewrite the subdirectories to the root of the project.

However, I'm not sure how to get the branches to behave like I want using `git-filter-branch` and.

Also it would be ideal to create a single git repo that has different branches for the "trunk" of each project, I would have no problem not really having a master in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was cloning the root of the repository and copying that new git repo for each project and rearranging things.  It wasn't clean or pretty, but it was legacy code that I no longer need to look at very often.

Answer (score 5):

Did you consider **[svn2git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn/572898#572898)** in order to import your svn into a git repository ?

It is better than  `git svn clone` because if you have this code in svn:

```
  trunk
    ...
  branches
    1.x
    2.x
  tags
    1.0.0
    1.0.1
    1.0.2
    1.1.0
    2.0.0
```

**`git-svn`** will go through the commit history to build a new git repo.
It **will import all branches and tags as remote svn branches, whereas what you really want is git-native local branches and git tag objects**.
So after importing this project, you would get:

```
  $ git branch
  * master
  $ git branch -a
  * master
    1.x
    2.x
    tags/1.0.0
    tags/1.0.1
    tags/1.0.2
    tags/1.1.0
    tags/2.0.0
    trunk
  $ git tag -l
  [ empty ]
```

After svn2git is done with your project, you'll get this instead:

```
  $ git branch
  * master
    1.x
    2.x
  $ git tag -l
    1.0.0
    1.0.1
    1.0.2
    1.1.0
    2.0.0
```

Finally, it makes sure the HEAD of master is the same as the current trunk of the svn repo.

So in your case, it would give you actual git branches to apply `git-filter-branch`.

Comment: I haven't, that's new to me.  I'll investigate.  Thanks!

Comment: That didn't actually work.  It left out a whole year's worth of commits.

Comment: As it turns out, it may have been something up with my machine.  git svn clone also started to fail for me.  Eventually, we were able to clone the thing, though massaged the history a bit differently.

Comment: VonC, there don't appear to be any files to download for svn2git at the URL you've provided?

Comment: @Peter: svn2git now links to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn/572898#572898, where more up-to-date svn2git repos are mentioned.