# How to make an existing git branch track a remote SVN branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-svn

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650), how can I make an existing Git branch track a remote SVN branch?

I often find that I start work in a local branch that I then need to push to an SVN server. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea remains to push to an *existing* SVN branch.

Meaning you need:

- to `git svn rebase` an existing SVN branch (called here '`git-svn-branch`')
- `git branch -b work` # new working branch
- work...
- `git checkout git-svn-branch` and `git svn rebase` (make sure master is up-to-date)
- `git checkout work` and `git rebase git-svn-branch` (replay your work on top of the git-svn branch)
- `git checkout git-svn-branch` and `git merge work` (update `git-svn-branch HEAD` to `work HEAD`)
- `git svn dcommit`  (push back the git-svn branch to SVN repo, with work commits included in it)

You will find that same process in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609872/workflow-and-help-with-git-2-svn-projects-and-a-single-workcopy).

So, in short, when you are working on a local Git branch, and you want to push it to an SVN branch, you need first to import that SVN branch to a 'git-svn' local branch, and then rebase/merge your local branch on it.
You cannot directly push your local Git branch on an SVN remote one.