# git-svn isn't committing to branches, only trunk

Tags: svn, git, git-svn, branch

I'm working with an SVN repository that is laid out like this:

```
$SVN/[project]/trunk
$SVN/[project]/branches/[user]/[branch]
$SVN/[project]/tags/releases/[tag]
```

My .git/config looks like this:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
  url = $SVN   
  fetch = project/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk   
  branches = project/branches/*/*:refs/remotes/*
```

When I look at git branch -a, I see all the remote branches. Let's say I want to check one out, work on it, then commit the changes back. Here's is what I am trying to do:

```
git checkout -b comments erik/comments
.... work, commit locally ....
git svn dcommit
```

However, dcommit always pushes to $SVN/project/trunk. `git svn info` always reports the URL as $SVN/project/trunk

I've tried using --track, I've tried reseting with --hard. I'm out of ideas here. I suspect it's my [svn-remote], but that's just a hunch.

Answer (score 1):

Does the branch `erik/comments` exist in SVN already?

I work as follows:

```
git svn fetch #update any newly created branches
git checkout davec/new-feature # on remote branch, git may warn you
git checkout -b new-feature davec/new-feature # assumes this exists in SVN
# hack
# commit
git svn dcommit
```

I realize that `git checkout -b local remote` is a one-step version of what I do in two steps, however this seems to work.

Another option is to replace your config with your username, e.g.

```
branches = project/branches/erik/*:refs/remotes/*
```

And then

```
git checkout new-feature # remote branch
git checkout -b new-feature-branch # local
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [svn2git, and git2svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn/572898#572898), as they do take into account non-standard SVN layouts.

They do use the `--tags` and `--branches` parameters of [`git svn`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn), and even if you do not use the scripts I mentioned above, you can use those parameters to get the data in the right places in your svn repository.