# Why is git-svn trying to use an old branch point?

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm trying to rely more heavily on git-svn for all my tasks, rather than just use git locally and then svn to handle server branches and tags.

I did a brand new clone of my svn repository.  I had to start from a fairly recent (300 revisions or so back) revision to prevent it taking days to clone.  git svn fetch and git svn dcommit are all working fine.

I'm trying to tag with our latest build number, 3.6.1.  So to do a dry-run I issue:

```
$ git svn tag -n -m "3.6.1 build" 3.6.1
Copying https://svnserver:8443/svn/TheProject/trunk at r5735 to https://svnserver:8443/svn/TheProject/tags/3.6.1...
branch_from: /tags => /tags/3.3.5
Found possible branch point: https://svnserver:8443/svn/TheProject/tags/3.3.5 => https://svnserver:8443/svn/TheProject/tags/3.3.5, 5726
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/tags/3.3.5@5726
Found possible branch point: https://svnserver:8443/svn/TheProject/trunk => https://svnserver:8443/svn/TheProject/tags/3.3.5, 2309
...I cancel as it starts listing all the files it'll add to svn...
```

I don't really get what's happening here.  Why is it going back so far to determine a branch point?  Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still unsure WHY it needed it, but it looks like it needed a "git svn fetch" so git knew about other branches and tags before it could do the new one.  After that (long-running) fetch, it's able to branch/tag perfectly.