# Git-SVN with multiple branch locations?

Tags: git, git-svn

Our company subversion repo is a bit tricky: We've got a basic "default" layout with trunk, tags and branches. However, inside the branches, we have a "work" directory which contains more branches. Something like this:

- branches/release_1_0_x
- branches/release_1_1_x
- branches/work/dave/topic_one
- branches/work/tom/topic_two
- branches/work/something_else

Now how can I get git-svn to recognize all those (and a few more) as separate branches? It appears `git svn init` only accepts one branch location, how ever I'm invoking it.

**Edit**: this is how I initialized the git repo:

```
git svn clone  -s --prefix=svn/ http://svn.company.com/product/
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn), your best bet is to use Git 1.6.x and take advantage of "deep cloning".

If you can't upgrade to 1.6.x, then you can specify multiple branches when you clone.

```
git svn clone -s --prefix=svn/ -b branches -b branches/work/dave -b branches/work/tom ...
```

You'll just have to make sure you add info for new users to your `.git/config` before "`git svn fetch`"ing when a new user branch has been added.

Comment: what does this make your .git/config file look like, since I'm using git 1.7 and would like to do this retroactively?

Comment: I've tried this, but it also has a branch called "work".  Is there a way to make it thing "work" is not its own branch but that "work/something_else" is?  Possibly with --ignore-paths?

Answer (score 31):

You can add multiple branches and tags entries in your git-svn config, even retroactively. So if normally SVN branches live in `branches/*` in your SVN repo (ie. a standard layout), but you also have `branches/summer-students/*`, you can set it up in `.git/config` like below:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn+ssh://svn.example.com
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*

    branches = branches/summer-students/*:refs/remotes/svn-summer-students/*
```

On the left of the `:` is the path in the SVN Repo, and on the right is the path it will appear as in your git remote branch list. You can use `refs/remotes/*` repeatedly to have everything appear as a top-level remote branch, but watch out for name collisions - they will break things (hence `svn-summer-students` instead of `summer-students`, which already exists).

After you edit the config, you need to delete `.git/svn/.metadata` and run `git svn fetch` to refresh the branch list and regenerate it. `git branch -r` should then show the extra branches. If you get errors, look out for naming collisions.

The [git svn docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) have some more examples of specifying paths via wildcards or expressions if you have a funky SVN layout.

Answer (score 14):

For those looking to do this retroactively, the [git-svn manpage for 1.7.x](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) says:

> It is also possible to fetch a subset
>   of branches or tags by using a
>   comma-separated list of names within
>   braces. For example:

```
[svn-remote "huge-project"]
     url = http://server.org/svn
     fetch = trunk/src:refs/remotes/trunk
     branches = branches/{red,green}/src:refs/remotes/branches/*
     tags = tags/{1.0,2.0}/src:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

Comment: Thanks!  In my case, I could not get it to clone like this, but I cloned, edited .git/config to add the branches as listed and reran `git svn fetch`.  Now `git branch -a` or `git branch -r` show the branches - woot!