# How should I switch to trunk after I cloned an entire SVN repository with git-svn?

Tags: git, git-svn

I cloned an entire SVN repository ( including all the branches ), using git-svn. The problem is, if I run `git branch` I don't get anything back. If I run `git branch -a` I get:

```
git-svn
```

What should I do now to start working on SVN's `trunk`?

EDIT: The repo is organized in the standard layout, but when I pulled I did it like:

```
git svn clone http://server/repo ( without any other options )
```

and not like

```
git svn clone http://server/repo/trunk
```

My gitconfig looks like this:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn_url
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

Comment: just checking, is the original svn repo organized in the usual standard layout of branches/tags/trunk? normally trunk is mapped to master, so you should have the master branch at the very least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid a complete reclone you can just update the `.git/config` file with the following:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
url = http://server.org/svn
fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

Then delete `.git/svn/.metadata` and run `git svn fetch` again

PS: This was inspired from what I found out from [Git-SVN with multiple branch locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638478/git-svn-with-multiple-branch-locations) when I had to deal with some repo with non-standard layout.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `-s` (standard layout) switch when cloning:

```
git svn -s clone http://server/repo
```

This switch will tell git-svn to create branches and tags from the directories found in `^/branches`, respectively `^/tags`. `^/trunk` will be mapped to git's `master` branch.

I'm afraid, you will have to re-clone your svn repository …

Comment: I hope you haven't deleted the directory, from my previous experience you just need to delete the metadata files, and do a fetch again. This will avoid the need to re-download all the objects

Comment: refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638478/git-svn-with-multiple-branch-locations

Comment: oh well, but at least you will not repeat this again :)

Answer (score 1):

You may clone SVN repostiory with [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html). It detects your trunk/branches/tags configuration and configures the layout correctly, so you have not to bother about it.