# git svn specify branches and tags on a non standard svn repository layout

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

The layout is :

```
Branches\
    Project1/
        Branch11/
        ...
        Branch1N/
    Project2/
        Branch21/
    ProjectX/   # not anywhere else
Excluded1\
Excluded2\
Excluded3\
Excluded4\
Programs\
    Excluded11\
    ...
    Excluded1N\
    Project1/   # the main one
    Project2/
    ...
    ProjectN/
Tags\
    Project1/
        Release1/
        ...
        Release69/
```

*Excluded* I managed to exclude - but I am completely unable to understand how can I map branches/tags to git branches/tags - preferably after the fact (each clone takes ~5 hours).

Please bear in mind I am new to SVN - I know not nor do I understand the branching/tagging system.

I am on *windoz* - svn2git is no option (anyway I am interested in how I do this after the clone or at worse cloning again but with vanilla git *only*)
Also I do not intend this as a permanent migration, it will function as a bridge between the SVN and the new git repo used in dev - so I want to keep as much info as possible - but no more than needed. At some point it might become permanent - where upon I will need to filter out empty commits (to the excluded projects) I guess (?)

[Repo](https://sourceforge.net/p/oblivionworks/code/3008/tree/)

Command :

> $ git svn clone --ignore-paths="^(?:Releases|Projects|Scripts|Games|)/|^Programs/(?:Nif Scanner|Nif Viewer|Raziel23x's Oblivion Toolset|Shader Disasm|Shader Editor)/" --authors-file=authors_with_emails.txt svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/oblivionworks/code/ .

After the clone I have :

```
$ git branch -r
  git-svn
$ git branch
* master
```

**Recap** : I have [cloned the thing](https://github.com/Utumno/wrye_bash_refactoring) excluding what I wanted to exclude - now I want to say to git "create a git branch for each of those svn branches - a real git branch that calculates the deltas and compresses them and deletes the folder `Branches` -  and track them - and this (700 mb) tags directory is just tags - what could you do about that (they do <del>not</del> correspond to commits) ?"
I see no <del>evil</del> trunk

My `config` :

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[svn-remote "svn"]
    ignore-paths = ^(?:Releases|Projects|Scripts|Games|)/|^Programs/(?:Nif Scanner|Nif Viewer|Raziel23x's Oblivion Toolset|Shader Disasm|Shader Editor)/
    url = svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/oblivionworks/code
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
[svn]
    authorsfile = authors_with_emails.txt
[gui]
    wmstate = zoomed
    geometry = 787x377+54+59 305 1127
[remote "github"]
    url = https://github.com/Utumno/wrye_bash_refactoring.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = github
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 2):

For Branches:

In your git config file you can control where the svn branches are located:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
url = file:///some.url.to/svn/dir
fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
branches = Branches/*/*:refs/remotes/*
```

So you are able to setup the different references to the branches.

OK so you can do the same for tags - cause in svn, tags and branches are so similar.

```
branches = Tags/*:refs/remotes/*
```

But you want "real" git tags, no problem, once you have them referenced as branches, you can modify your git repo again to make good git tag references:

```
git-for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin/tags | cut -d / -f 5- |
while read ref
do
git tag -a "$ref" -m"say farewell to SVN" "refs/remotes/origin/tags/$ref"
git push origin ":refs/heads/tags/$ref"
git push origin tag "$ref"
done
```

Obviously, you will need to slightly modify these scripts for your purposes.

Comment: Will try those asap - meanwhile could you explain a bit what the scripts actually do - especially the `[svn-remote "svn"]` ? What is the trunk they refer to ? _Will this get the "branches" actually compressed into the git database and out of my face_ ? It would help (me at least) if you had a look at the actual repo and provided some example code for that. You need also to elaborate a bit on the logic of the mappings I don't understand - the problem is the struct of the repo. Added the config

Comment: Also - there is no trunk - and you do not address the issue of creating git branches - real git branches that know they are just deltas - so `Branches/
    Project1/
        Branch11/` should know it is a branch out of the files in `Programs/Project1/`

Comment: `[svn-remote "svn"] url = svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/oblivionworks/code fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn branches = Branches/*/*:refs/remotes/*` and then `rm .git/svn/.metadata` and then `git svn fetch` and now I have the branches unrooted as remote branches - where do I go from here ? `$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/git-svn
  remotes/github/master
  remotes/svn-branches/CBash/dev-sharlikran
  remotes/svn-branches/Wrye%20Bash/291-fixes
  # ...
  remotes/svn-branches/Wrye%20Flash/Fallout%203
  remotes/svn-branches/Wrye%20Flash/Fallout%20NV`

Comment: You can now track these branches from local repository branches (remember git is distributed). So a command such as `git checkout --track -b Fallout3 svn-branches/branches/Wrye%20Flash/Fallout%203` your remote is called svn-branches according to the output of your branches.  which also means you want to use `[svn-remote "svn-branches"]` in the previous config.

Comment: So do I have to make a new section in the config ? Also is there an easy way to checkout a local branch foreach remote one and run `git svn rebase` on it ? According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1430782/281545) that is what I have to do. _Will this "root" my branches back to the tree_ ? See also [here](http://www.bild.me/bild.php?file=4960938git_svn.jpg) - are those the `Found possible branch point` reports during `fetch` ? Please update your answer a bit - I will be happy to accept it but it is still lacking info

Comment: `Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history` after `git checkout -b b_CBash_dev-sharlikran -t 'refs/remotes/svn-branches/CBash/dev-sharlikran'` followed by `git svn rebase 'refs/remotes/svn-branches/CBash/dev-sharlikran'` - will try with the WB branches which [seem](http://www.bild.me/bild.php?file=4960938git_svn.jpg) to have some info - EDIT : Nope - `Unable to determine...` - stuck. Did I mess it up by putting `branches = Branches/*/*:refs/remotes/svn-branches/*` in the config (my previous comment was wrong) ? Can I use the `291-fixes@1502` pictured somehow ?

Comment: git is different than git in that each clone of a repo is a fork, this means that you have references to your remote repository, but to start working locally, you have to create each branch - but you only need the branches that you are going to alter, so you can get them as you need them, you could easily script a loop around the branch creation commands to create all your branches.

I think you want to read a bit more about git-rebase, it should not be necessary directly after fetching unless you want to rebase a current working branch.  When you fetch you only get the refs.

Comment: Thanks I know about git - what I am trying to do is to recreate the history - git is clever enough to produce messages like `Found possible branch point: svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/oblivionworks/code/Programs/Wrye%20Bash => svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/oblivionworks/code/Branches/Wrye%20Bash/
295-fixes, 1667
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/svn-branches/Wrye Bash/295-fixes@1667` so I am trying to make it recreate the tree. As it is those branches are "unrooted" and I am sure there is a way to "rebase" them on the master branch. Maybe I have to reclone ? Same goes for tags ofc - as it is it's 700 mb

Comment: I recloned with `--branches=Branches/Wrye\ Bash/* --tags=Tags/Wrye\ Bash/* --trunk=Programs/Wrye\ Bash/ --prefix=svn/` and I'll see how it goes (notice this time I only clone branches and tags for the particular project) - the way you suggested (`branches = Branches/*/*:refs/remotes/*`) when I checked out a branch it would check it out right inside the `Programs` dir - could you amend your answer to address this ?

Comment: So how to edit the config so it maps the branches to the correct Projects - after the clone - see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413476/git-svn-specify-branches-and-tags-on-a-non-standard-svn-repository-layout#comment26149702_17900029)?

Comment: Alright I am giving you +1 (and half) as I used some of your insights but I am still looking for an answer

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this recently.

First of all, I'm not sure why you want to rearrange everything *after* moving out of svn into git. I doubt that's possible.

Second, I wouldn't dream of doing this without svn2git. I'm not sure what the Windows problem is you're referring to - svn2git is written in Ruby. I don't do Windows if I can avoid it, but surely there's a Ruby implementation for Windows, through Cygwin if nothing else.

Third, and this was the key, I used svndumpfilter to get the *svn* repo just the way I wanted it (i.e., in a form that svn2git would happily consume) *before* converting. This took some trial and error but it worked really well in the end.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate and http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering (adjust links for your SVN version) for more info.

EDIT: I would have made this a comment but it's too long. I think the best you'll be able to do is something like this:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    ignore-paths = ^(?:Releases|Projects|Scripts|Games|)/|^Programs/(?:Nif Scanner|Nif Viewer|Raziel23x's Oblivion Toolset|Shader Disasm|Shader Editor)/
    url = svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/oblivionworks/code
    fetch = Programs/Wrye Bash:refs/remotes/git-svn/Wrye Bash
    branches = Branches/Wrye Bash/*:refs/remotes/git-svn/Wrye Bash/branches/*
    fetch = Programs/Skyrim Viewer:refs/remotes/git-svn/Skyrim Viewer
    fetch = Programs/CBash:refs/remotes/git-svn/CBash
    branches = Branches/CBash/*:refs/remotes/git-svn/CBash/branches/*
# etc.
```

That is, a `fetch`, and, if applicable, a `branches` line for each program you're interested in. Like in the answer you linked to, you'd have to purge the `.git/svn/.metadata` file before doing `git svn fetch` again.

But this does nothing to affect my earlier comment: it is still the case that your git history is completely linear and does not reflect the actual branching and merging history of your project. This will not be what you want if you make this a permanent migration.

Comment: Thank you but 3 is not an option - and I said that svn2git is not an option - after all is not nuclear physics - there must be a way to be done in git alone. But I'd like to have some input on your 1st point - why not after the fact (ie the clone) ? I can certainly add new branches after the fact so why can't I say "hey git this `branches` folder is just branches - so absorb them in your objects"

Comment: You said that _since_ you're on Windows, it _followed_ that you could not use svn2git. I'm questioning that conclusion and suggesting that maybe you could use svn2git after all.

A 'branch' in git is a pointer to a particular commit. No more, no less. What you really want to capture in git is the _history_ of how the files changed and merged. 'Calculating the diffs' is going to involve replaying every change as a git commit, which is what git-svn does. Whatever you do, it's going to involve replaying all the commits into a fresh empty git repo, whether you 'start' from svn or  git.

Comment: Thanks - yes I should edit the question probably - I meant I don't really want to install cygwin and ruby and read the svn2git docs etc - I want to do it via git _only_. I know it can be done in windows but really I'd rather stay vanilla this time (among other things cause I want to understand exactly what goes on).

Comment: Now - I perfectly understand what a branch is in git. But - see the repo structure in the question - is it possible to tell git "hey those are branches and guess what - they correspond to commits in the `Programs/Project1/` files". I guess this involves 1. what @Michael said (plus ...?) 2. creating the git branches somehow and point them to the remotes and 3. hopefully only running `git svn fetch` (or `git svn rebase` or...) - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1430782/281545)

Comment: The problem at the moment is that the git history you ended up with is completely linear. You didn't tell `git svn clone` where to look for branches, so it completely ignored any branching or merging. I'm pretty sure (definitely not 100% sure) this has to be done at `git svn clone` (or `git svn init`) time. See the documentation for the `--follow-parent`, -`--trunk`, `--tags`, `--branches`, and `--stdlayout` options to `git svn`.

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6132228/281545) then ? _My_ gut feeling tells me it is certainly possible - I wouldn't throw my rep if not - anyway I now regret not using --prefix - although maybe not too late for this either

Comment: Aha - thanks - well how about adding the code to map the branches to git branches - cause I think that if this is added too and I purge the .metadata and git rebuilds it - maybe I will see the tree after all - or there may be a way - but I certainly need the git branches - EDIT : `error: 'refs/remotes/git-svn' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/git-svn/Wrye%20Bash' fatal: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/git-svn/Wrye%20Bash'`. EDIT2 : `fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn branches = Branches/*/*:refs/remotes/*`- fetching...