# Git-svn migration with non-standard layout doesn't show merges

Tags: git, svn, version-control, merge, git-svn

After trying several options and a bunch of hints from this site and others I'm stuck. My main question is the following: I'd like to migrate (part of) an SVN repository to Git, preserving history. The SVN layout is non-standard and after `git svn clone` I do see the right branches appear, but when I try to e.g. merge `master` into a branch, I get conflicts that say both added a set of files. If I take a look in e.g. `gitg` I see the branches, but they never seem to branch from `master`/trunk (so the "both added" conflicts seem logical from that perspective), nor do I see any of the merges (e.g. from trunk to a branch) in the graph (the commits are there, they just don't link to branches in the graphical display of `gitg`). In fact, for some branches I even see two identical commits one after the other (one for master, one for the branch).
The way I created the branches in SVN was using `svn copy`.

Some more details:

**Repository layout:** A slightly simplified schematic of the SVN repo layout (the structure is the same, names are different, some directories have been omitted)

```
pkg
    Project1
    Project2
    Lib
branches
    Project1-feature1
        Project1
        Lib
    Project1-hotfix
        Project1
        Lib
    Lib-feature
tags
    Project1
        v0.1.0
        v0.2.0
            Project1
            Lib
    Project2
        v0.1.0
```

The `Lib` directory is closely associated with Project1, but also used by others. That is why I (starting with v0.2.0) created to `Project1` and `Lib` subdirectory structure in the branches and tags.

**My `git svn` workflow**: This is the most promising command I used to clone the SVN repo:

```
git svn clone \             
    --prefix=svn/ \
    --trunk=pkg \
    --branches=branches \
    --tags=tags/Project1 \
    -A authors.txt \
    --ignore-paths='^pkg/(?!Project1|Lib)' \
    svn+ssh://user@svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/MyTool  SVN2GitMigration
```

The `--ignore-paths` option is there so that I keep only the two directories (`Project` and `Lib`) in which I'm interested. I do not filter on branches since there is only one branch not directly related to `Project1`.

After that I convert the remote branches to local branches (and remove the remote branches), then convert the tags to proper Git tags.

**EDIT START:** Closer inspection of the commits reveals that I have many empty commits. These turn out to be due to the `--ignore-paths` option: the empty commits are done in parts of the directory tree that are ignored. So this option doesn't really behave as I expected. 
Back to the drawing board...
**EDIT END**

**EDIT2** 
Actually, using `git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty -- --all` I managed to remove the empty commits
**EDIT2 END**

**Possible cause of my merge problems:** Branches/Tags are not single SVN commits because they first consist of a commit in which I create the `branches/Project1-featureX` directory, followed by two `svn copy` lines in which I copy the `Project1` and `Lib` directories from trunk.

Suggestions on how to properly convert this SVN repo are very welcome! If, somehow this means loosing `Lib` that isn't a big deal. I'm planning to separate the two anyway once the migration has finished.

Comment: I guess you could try with separate `Project1`, `Project2` and `Lib`. After all they are supposed to be split into separate repositories in git.

Comment: Splitting the projects is indeed my intention. In fact, the other projects are easy because they don't have branches and only some have tags (a linear history). So there a simple `git svn clone --prefix=svn/ --trunk=pkg/Project3 -A authors.txt $SVNURL Project3_Git`. What complicates matters for Project1 is probably the way I created the branches. Or do I misunderstand your point?

Comment: git-svn support wildcards when matching the branches, so you may try something like `--branches=branches/Project1-*` for your `Project1`

Comment: Hmmm, closer inspection of the result of the `git svn` command above shows me that I have many commits that are empty. I think the `--ignore-path` option is the cause. So... back to square one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I solved my problem in the following way:

### Preparation

First I initialised a repository without any branches or tags:

```
git svn init \
  --prefix=svn/ \
  --trunk=pkg/Project1 \
  svn+ssh://user@svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/MyTool \
  SVN2GitMigration
```

Next I added the author information:

```
cd SVN2GitMigration
git config svn.authorsfile ../authors.txt
```

After this, my `.git/config` file had the following contents:

```
[core]
       repositoryformatversion = 0
       filemode = true
       bare = false
       logallrefupdates = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
       url = svn+ssh://user@svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/MyTool \
       fetch = pkg/Project1:refs/remotes/svn/trunk
[svn]
       authorsfile = ../authors.txt
```

In order to get the branches and tags I changed that file to:

```
[core]
       repositoryformatversion = 0
       filemode = true
       bare = false
       logallrefupdates = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
       url = svn+ssh://user@svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/MyTool \
       fetch = pkg/Project1:refs/remotes/svn/trunk
       tags = tags/Project1/{v0.4.2,v0.4.1,v0.4.0,v0.3.0,v0.2.2,v0.2.0}/Project1:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*
       tags = tags/Project1/{v0.2.1,v0.1-9e,v0.1.3}:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*
       branches = branches/{Project1-v0.4.2-fixes,Project1-v0.4.1-fixes,Project1-refactor,Project1-feature1}/Project1:refs/remotes/svn/*
       branches = branches/{Project1-feature2}:refs/remotes/svn/*
[svn]
       authorsfile = ../authors.txt
```

Notice how each `branches` and `tags` line has a list of directory names in `{}`, even if it only contains one directory name. Without this, the fetching won't work.

### Download the SVN data

To download and convert the SVN repository run:

```
git svn fetch
```

### Postprocessing

After this, some post-processing is required. To convert the remove tags and branches to proper local tags and branches and delete the remote ones run:

```
for branch in `git branch -r |grep -v tags| grep -v trunk | sed 's/svn\///'`; do
     git branch $branch remotes/svn/$branch;
done
for tag in `git branch -r |grep tags| sed 's;svn/tags/;;'`; do
      git tag $tag remotes/svn/tags/$tag;
done
for br in `git branch -r`; do
      git branch -d -r $br
done
```

Convert the `svn:ignore` properties to a `.gitignore` file

```
git svn show-ignore > .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Added .gitignore file based on the svn:ignore properties"
```

After inspecting the git repo with `gitg` or `gitk` it turned out that many merges were missing (not show in the graph), so I had to graft those by hand by adding the parent commit hashes to the `.git/info/grafts` file (the file format is `merge_hash parent1_hash parent2_hash`). Note that `gitk` shows the grafts, whereas `gitg` doesn't until they are made permanent.

To make the commits permanent use

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

and to remove the backups created by `git filter-branch` run:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
```

### Wrapping up

Now that everything is converted, clone the repository into a bare one:

```
git clone --bare SVN2GitMigration Project1.git
```

and push that to Github:

```
cd Project1.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/mygithubuser/Project1.git
```

### References

Thanks to the following sites for pointing to the right directions:

- http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git
- http://www.sailmaker.co.uk/blog/2013/05/05/migrating-from-svn-to-git-preserving-branches-and-tags-3/
- http://blokspeed.net/blog/2010/09/converting-from-subversion-to-git/
- http://blog.agavi.org/post/16865375185/fixing-svn-merge-history-in-git-repositories
- http://patrickbougie.com/2013/03/18/convert-svn-to-git-repository/
- [git svn specify branches and tags on a non standard svn repository layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413476/git-svn-specify-branches-and-tags-on-a-non-standard-svn-repository-layout)