# Work with Git and SVN at the same time

Tags: svn, git

I am participing in a Free Software Contest, and we have to use a forge that uses GForge, with only support for SVN, but I will like to use Git (using gitorious) for example.

There is a simple way to get two repositories (one on SVN and other with Git) updated more or less at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

This would remain a two-step operation, but some [script like **git2svn**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn/572898#572898) can help you update your svn quickly once you have pushed your commit to the gitorious Git repo.

Answer (score 0):

We are doing something on a similar vein, as we wanted to use Gource to show how pretty our source code was.

[here is a link to what the gource site suggests](http://code.google.com/p/gource/wiki/SVN)

So I setup a scheduled task to perform every 6 hours (you could do yours more often of course) which would use the `git svn fetch` function to pull the latest revisions from our svn server to our git install.

It may be possible to do it as part of your Constant Build Server functionallity, I think that's the right term? (as your cruise control, teamcity, or other builds you could perform a git conversion).

Cheers

Luke

(P.S:  never could get the git svn rebase to work properly, so am constantly performing a fetch)