# How to reinitialize a git-svn repository

Tags: git, git-svn

Following the advice of [this tutorial](http://www.viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/), I cloned an svn repository which did not have the standard layout.

> ```
> git-svn clone -s http://example.com/my_subversion_repo local_dir
> ```
>
> The -s is there to signify that my Subversion repository has a standard layout (trunk/, branches/, and tags/.) If your repository doesn’t have a standard layout, you can leave that off.

Being completely new to git, I did not realize that simply leaving off the -s option without supplementing the --trunk, --branches, and --tags options would leave me not only with a branchless repository but also with the entire head of the repository checked out (instead of just the head of the trunk).

Is there a way to "fix" my local git repository to behave as though I had created it with knowledge of the svn repository layout?  Can I use git-svn init to reinitialize my repository?  Because of the length of time involved, I'm hoping to avoid having to reclone from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to [SO question "Cloning a Non-Standard Svn Repository with Git-Svn"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn), and I am not sure there is a process to fix the Git repo after that initial clone.

The deep clone is the official way:

```
git svn clone https://svn.myrepos.com/myproject web-self-serve 
   --trunk=trunk --branches=branches/*/*
```

But I like the encapsulation provided by **[svn2git](http://github.com/iteman/svn2git)**.

Unfortunately, both those solutions require re-cloning from scratch...