# How to clone a nonstandard svn repo to git?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-clone

I try to clone a svn repo to git, but some of the branches are in the svn root dir like follows.

I've tried

```
$ git clone svn://url/svn-root -T trunk -b branches -b branch1 -b branch2
```

and

```
$ git clone svn://url/svn-root -T trunk -b branches -b .
```

Both are failed to clone the `branch1` and `branch2` correctly. Please help.

```
svn-root
├── branch1
├── branch2
├── branches
│   ├── branch3
│   └── branch4
└── trunk
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One interesting tool, mentioned in [GitMinutes Episode 20](http://episodes.gitminutes.com/2013/08/gitminutes-20-mick-wever-on-migrating.html), is [**SubGit**](http://subgit.com/stash/import/), a plugin for [Atalssian Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash/overview) (which isn't free, but you can try it for free).
You can know much more about SubGit in "[GitMinutes #22: Alexander Kitaev about SubGit](http://episodes.gitminutes.com/2013/09/gitminutes-22-alexander-kitaev-about.html)".

It is designed to managed unconventional svn repo layout.

[image: http://subgit.com/img/stash/105_repository_layout.png]

[Dmitry Pavlenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1212681/dmitry-pavlenko) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693377/how-to-clone-a-nonstandard-svn-repo-to-git/18693798#comment27556401_18693798):

> you should enter in the "Branches" field:

```
*:refs/heads/*;branches/*:refs/heads/branches/* 
# instead of 
branches/*
```

> In this case `branch1` will be translated to `refs/heads/branch1`,
>   `branch3` --- to `refs/heads/branches/branch3`.
>
> Alternatively, if you have limited number of top-level branches, you can enumerate them explicitly:

```
branch1:refs/heads/branch1;
branch2:refs/heads/branch2;
branches/*:refs/heads/bra‌​nches/*
```

Comment: I'll add that for your case you should enter `*:refs/heads/*;branches/*:refs/heads/branches/*` instead of `branches/*` in "Branches" field. In this case `branch1` will be translated to `refs/heads/branch1`, `branch3` --- to `refs/heads/branches/branch3`. Alternatively, if you have limited number of top-level branches, you can enumerate them explicitly: `branch1:refs/heads/branch1;branch2:refs/heads/branch2;branches/*:refs/heads/branches/*`

Comment: @DmitryPavlenko Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Can I get a local git repo to receive updates directly from the original svn repo by this approach, or I need to keep Atalssian as a transfer station?

Comment: @Eric I would recommend keeping the Atlassian tool for subsequent updates.

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind:

- Clean up your SVN repo first (Move branches below /branches, where they should be according to standard layout).
- Checkout using standard layout, add remote branch refs later on.

Comment: It is not my svn repo. So I can not use method 1. Can you provide more detail on method 2, especially on the step 'adding remote branch refs'. I briefly read 'git help svn' but did not find a solution.