# How to import a new tag from svn into git-svn?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

By @Vanuan's answer [How to import svn branches and tags into git-svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11918337/5218590) a svn repo with branches and tags are fetched into git-svn, but then how to import a new-upstream-created tag into git-svn?

---

### Use Case: Mirroring an active-developed svn repo

1. No write permission to the [svn repo](http://svn.pjsip.org/repos);
2. Sync new tags and branches with the svn repo;
3. Create new git-only branches, modify and commit to a [git repo](https://github.com/morris-stock/pjproject);

Answer (score 0):

git-svn assumes that you are using the git-svn repo to mirror an svn repo.  While it is a functioning git repo, any new branches and tags should be created using the [git-svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) tool. If tags and branches are added as regular 'git' branches and tags, then you'll need to transfer the code across yourself.

I'd suggest you try using `git stash` to save your local git-only branch changes, run `git svn fetch` to get the latest changes including any new tags, apply your git stash into a newly created git-svn branch and then use `git-svn dcommit` to commit them to your svn repo.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, but it will delete all my non-svn branches.

Comment: Hi @Morris, I've added extra details above which hopefully answers your question?

Comment: Hi @Paul, I run `java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar svn-migration-scripts.jar clean-git --no-delete`, but it still says "Deleting Git branch 'b-trunc' not in Subversion." in dry-run mode.

Comment: @Morris see new edits - it appears that the migration script I referenced doesn't support what you want to do.

Comment: ``git svn fetch`` does not fetch new tags in my case.

Comment: you are right, ``git svn fetch`` does fetch the latest tags. It just does not create a git ``tag``, which should be created manually in my case. Thank you so much.