# RW Access git repository using svn (git-svnserver)?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, git-svn

Is there a program that does what git-svn does, but in a situation where the repository on the server is git, and the developer uses svn?

I know that github.com allows svn access to the git repositories they host, but it doesn't look like they've released this project open source (yet?), and using their servers is not an option for me (not even their private repositories).

EDIT: I think what I am looking for is a parallel to 'git-cvsserver' -- git-svnserver. In a bit of searching, I found some 2-3 year old threads on the git mailing list, but it doesn't look like anyone has made significant progress. I hope someone can correct me on that.

Are there any git-svnserver projects currently underway? I'd hate to have duplicate effort, but it seems that [GitHub is the farthest along](http://github.com/blog/644-subversion-write-support), but nobody else can have it.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [SubGit](http://subgit.com).

*SubGit* is server-side solution, it enables Subversion access to Git repository and vice versa. You may refer to [documenation](http://subgit.com/documentation/) for more details, but in general it is fairly easy to use *SubGit*:

SubGit needs local access to Git repository you're pushing to. Create Subversion repository on the same machine:

```
    $ svnadmin create $SVN_REPOS
```

then run

```
    $ subgit configure $SVN_REPOS
```

This command creates `$SVN_REPOS/conf/subgit.conf` file, adjust its `git.default.repository` option just as follows:

```
    [git "default"]
    repository = /path/to/your/git/repository.git
```

You can specify many Git repositories synced to single Subversion repository, just add necessary `[git "identifier"]` sections.

You can also specify arbitrary repository layout, e.g. the standard one looks like this:

```
    trunk = trunk:refs/heads/master
    branches = branches/*:refs/heads/*
    shelves = shelves/*:refs/shelves/*
    tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

You can also adjust `$SVN_REPOS/conf/authors.txt` to map svn author names to git identities.

After that run:

```
    $ subgit install $SVN_REPOS
    $ ... let initial translation complete ... 
    $ TRANSLATION SUCCESSFUL
```

At this moment you have Subversion repository and its Git counterpart which are continuously synchronized, i.e. SubGit immediately translates svn revision into git commit on every `svn commit` and git commit into svn revision on every `git push`.

So, you can commit changes to created Subversion repository and keep all changes in sync with the main Git repository.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I'll keep my eye on it, and hopefully by the time it's ready for production, my company is ready to try it.

Answer (score 4):

This is Python code to serve a git repository over svn protocol:

http://git.q42.co.uk/git_svn_server.git

Comment: Down :( Anyone have a mirror? I'd be interested in picking up this project.

Comment: Site is up, but the last commit was 20 months ago.

Comment: This looks very useful but there is no documentation. Does anyone know of an example, a tutorial, or at least a README?

Answer (score 2):

[SVNGit](https://github.com/naver/svngit) is exactly what you want. It is an opensource servlet library for SVN clients to access Git repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `git-svn` link is meant to be driven by git (to monitor -- rebase or dcommit -- a SVN branch).
Meaning you could first clone whatever git repo you need on your local server (where you also use SVN), and use that for '`git-svn`' commands between your local Git repo and your SVN workspace.

Once your local Git repo reflects adequately your SVN repo, you can push back to the remote Git server.

Comment: I'm not sure this does what I want. This is only for my coworkers that wouldn't want to switch to git, because all they do in svn now is checkout/update/commit anyways. If they ever did need to do more, someone could hold their hand through actually using git.

Comment: @drhorrible: it still could be a solution: a script like [git2svn](http://repo.or.cz/w/git2svn.git) (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn/572898#572898) could setup their SVN history for them, the git repo being there then to be able to get back their SVN work in the local Git repo before being pushed back for the other Git users.