# How do I access svn branches using git-svn with a non-standard svn repo layout?

Tags: branch, git-svn, repository-design

The standard repo layout in svn is as follows.

```
/trunk
/branches
    featureX
    featureY
/tags
    1.0
    2.0
```

The repository I'm working with is a much flatter structure.

```
trunk
featureX
featureY
```

Essentially, trunk is at the same level as the other branches.  I can't use the -s or -b option with `git svn init` because of this.

How would I pull in `trunk` as the git branch `master` and pull in `featureX` as a git branch of the same name?  I don't care about any other branches or tags.

I've seen similar questions and people have suggested restructuring the svn repository.  This is off the table as far as this question is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out a way to pull in multiple branches from an arbitrary svn repository structure.

The `-b` option for `git svn init` will only work if all branches are grouped together within a subdirectory in the repository, such as in the standard layout.  If all branches, including the trunk, are side by side in the same folder, this won't really work.  You can pull in selected branches from the svn repository by essentially creating multiple "trunks" int your git repository.

Assume the flat structure from the question with the three branches trunk, featureX, and featureY.

1. Instantiate your git repository.

   ```
   mkdir myproject
   cd myproject
   git svn init url:to/svn/repo -T trunk
   ```

   This will create a git repository with svn metadata in the `.git/config` file.
2. Open the config file and examine the svn metadata

   ```
   vim .git/config
   ```

   Your config file will look something like this.

   ```
   [core]
     repositoryformatversion = 0
     filemode = true
     bare = false
     logallrefupdates = true
     autocrlf = false
   [svn-remote "svn"]
     url = url:to/svn/repo
     fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
   ```

   The `svn-remote` header defines a reference called "svn" pointing to your svn repository.  The `fetch` parameter tells git-svn where to pull new revisions from within the svn repository.  Now we need to tell git-svn about the other branch we're interested in.
3. Duplicate the `svn-remote` section

   Copy the entire `svn-remote` section of the config file and paste it below the existing config text.

   ```
   [core]
     repositoryformatversion = 0
     filemode = true
     bare = false
     logallrefupdates = true
     autocrlf = false
   [svn-remote "svn"]
     url = url:to/svn/repo
     fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
   [svn-remote "svn"]
     url = url:to/svn/repo
     fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
   ```
4. Modify the new `svn-remote` section

   Change the name of the `svn-remote` section header and the name of the branch that it points to.

   ```
   [core]
     repositoryformatversion = 0
     filemode = true
     bare = false
     logallrefupdates = true
     autocrlf = false
   [svn-remote "svn"]
     url = url:to/svn/repo
     fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
   [svn-remote "svn-featureX"]
     url = url:to/svn/repo
     fetch = featureX:refs/remotes/featureX
   ```

   Now git-svn will track both svn branches.  You can use the names "svn" and "svn-featureX" with any git-svn command that takes an `[svn-remote]` parameter.  You can use the names "trunk" and "featureX" with any git command that takes a remote branch name as a parameter.

This solution won't scale well, and is a bit of a hack to work with a malformed svn repository.  So long as you only need to track a handful of svn branches, this will work just fine.  If the number of svn branches you need to work with becomes too large, take a serious look at restructuring your svn repository to the standard layout.

Answer (score 1):

As this [article illustrates](http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763), you can write rules for running an importer tool like **[svn2git](http://gitorious.org/svn2git/svn2git)**
(you have less complete version of [svn2git here](http://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git))

See [those examples](http://gitorious.org/svn2git/svn2git/trees/master/samples) for rules that you could rewrite in order to match those flat SVN directories/branches and declare them as Git branches.

Comment: Note: for more up-ti-date svn2git repos, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn/572898#572898