# Export Entire Git Repo to SVN including Branches

Tags: svn, git, git-svn, git-branch

Long story short, I have a git repo with several branches, and I would like to move it to an SVN repo while maintaining all of the branches and commit history.

So far I have not had much luck, most of the methods I have found do not migrate the branches as I would expect. (they are combined, or ignored, or eaten by a grue)

I was planning on using git-svn (git locally, SVN remote) and from the documentation I got the impression that using Git with SVN in this manner was very possible.. . but no idiot proof tutorial was provided!

Is this possible?  if so how? If not what is it about git/svn do I not understand?

Comment: Since git was made to replace SVN, I don't think there is a lot of support for this out there.

Comment: I have given up (can't dedicate too much time to this,  I am going to merge down to one branch and then commit to the SVN (loosing logs and branches)  However.  I would like to leave this open as someone else might find a solution helpful.  (Perhaps their repo is more extensive than mine is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check **[git2svn](http://repo.or.cz/w/git2svn.git)** as detailed in question "[Cloning a Non-Standard Svn Repository with Git-Svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn/572898#572898)"?
It could help for this kind of conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend pushing your git branches to a svn repo.  When using git-svn, its typical that the git repo is a throwaway piece that helps to keep the svn repo clean and merge friendly.

The best practice, as I have found, is to merge your git branches and `git svn dcommit` just that branch to a checked out repository branch (don't checkout the entire svn repo).  Then again, you can create a svn branch as your scratch branch for this and do a manual merge from that branch to another in svn.