# xcode change from svn to git

Tags: iphone, ios, git, svn, xcode4

I am working on an iPhone app improvement project. Original project was done using SVN, however, I want to use git for new changes. When I open xcode4 and see source control, I dont see an option to change the source control settings. How can I change the settings so that I can use a local git repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to convert that svn repo to a git repo first, with git-svn for instance.
I would recommend using a script like [svn2git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn/572898#572898) for this kind of operation (that is, if you don't have to commit back to the original SVN repo. If you do, `git-svn` is preferable).