# Clone a git repository into subdirectory of a subversion repository

Tags: git, git-svn

I have an existing SVN repository, which has a "common" directory containing modules shared by different projects.
The layout is like this:

```
http://example.com/svn/trunk/common/module_1
http://example.com/svn/trunk/common/module_2
...
http://example.com/svn/trunk/common/module_X
```

For various reasons, I'm managing some other projects with git.
I need to use **module_X** in both SVN and git projects, so I'm planning to use git-svn.
However, the following problem occurs:

```
user@host:/repos$ git svn clone http://example.com/svn/trunk/common/module_X destination
```

This command will create a new git repository in **/repos/destination** and fetches **module_X** content into it.
What I need to accomplish is to put **module_X** in in **/repos/destination/module_X**, not to fetch it's content directly into **/repos/destination/**.

What seemed an option in the beginning was to use

```
user@host:/repos$ git svn clone =--ignore-paths='^((?!module_X).*)$' http://example.com/svn/trunk/common/ destination
```

which will make a repository in **/repos/destination**, and a subdirectory **/repos/destination/module_X**.
But the problem is that my SVN repository has a rather large revision history and opreations on the whole **common/** path are rather slow.

Does anyone have idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

short answer : you can't, or you don't want. Git has not been designed to host multiple projects, and thus clone independant subdirectories, one git == one project. Even though you **can** do it (look at the very insightful answer of : [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)), you will loose all ability to keep uptodate with the updates.

There may be one hack though you could try, is to tell git-svn to create a branch for each module you have, here you have a good example : [Cloning a Non-Standard Svn Repository with Git-Svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn), something that should look like:

```
% git svn clone https://svn.myrepos.com/myproject myproject --ignore-paths='^((?!common).*)$' --trunk=trunk/ --branches=trunk/common/* --prefix=svn/
```

(untested)