# Using git svn clone on a subversion repository with inconsistent branches

Tags: git, svn, import, branch

My question looks at first sight similar to others (notably [Cloning a Non-Standard Svn Repository with Git-Svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn/) ) but I have one additional problem. I am also aware of http://john.albin.net/git/git-svn-migrate .

Some of the branches that were created in the svn repository left out the top-level directory in the trunk. So in the branch, all files appear to differ from the files in the trunk, merely because they are in a different location.

Example: in one of the branches, the directory `trunk/top/src` corresponds to `branches/foo/bar/src` instead of the more usual `branches/foo/bar/top/src`. But there are also branches that use the second form.

Now when running `git svn clone` on this svn repository, it will re-trace the full history of such branches and double all commits to them. On the trunk the commit will be for file `top/src/file` and on the branch it will be for `src/file`. Because the `git svn fetch` operation apparently isn't clever enough to detect this relocation, it will go back the full history prior to the creation of the branch and create new commits for the new location, going back all the way to the beginning of time, just so that it can create the files that are going into the branch.

Since there are a lot of branches, and the later ones have a lot of history, this is annoying situation, since each commit is doubled or tripled (although from a cursory inspection it seems that the "alternate" location of each file is shared for some-but-not-all pre-history of the branches that it later is going to occur in). And it really adds to the conversion time, too.

Now what I've been thinking about to fix that is the following. What if it were possible to insert some hook in the code of `git svn fetch` (it is a Perl script) that would edit the paths of the files involved after it fetches them from svn, but before it commits them to git. If the pathname of a file would not contain the `top` directory, it would insert it, otherwise it would leave the name alone. This way I effectively rewrite history as we go along.

Now the following questions spring to mind:

1. Is this a sane idea?
2. If yes, how can I do it?
3. If no, what else could I do?
   The origin repository is still in use, so solutions that make it impossible or difficult to import future commits are unfortunately not helpful.

In addition to this, I will start in a non-empty destination repository and skip the first part of the svn history. This is because the beginning was converted from cvs, where its tags from that time were converted in a rather strange and useless way, and I have already created a script to re-do that part from scratch.

(Yes, as of 2019 I am still looking for an answer...)