# Setting up git-svn to follow a non-standard svn repo

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

Here's the structure of my SVN repo:

- `http://server.net:8080/svn/CompanyName` — svn root
- `http://server.net:8080/svn/CompanyName/ProjectBranch3` — current branch of the project
- `http://server.net:8080/svn/CompanyName/ProjectBranch2` — previous branch of the project
- `http://server.net:8080/svn/CompanyName/ProjectBranch1` — first branch of the project
- `http://server.net:8080/svn/CompanyName/SomeRandomProject` — another project in the same root that I **don't want to check out**. There are lot of them
- `http://server.net:8080/svn/CompanyName/Tags/ProjectName/` — tags for the project

Project was developed as `ProjectBranch1` at first, then copied into `ProjectBranch2`, and `ProjectBranch3` in the end. I want to fetch the project with all of it's history, and I want git to understand that each branch started where previous one finished.

Now, the `git init` command has a `-b` option to specify a subfolder that is used for branches. However, the svn branches are not contained to a subfolder; as described above, they are located right in the root as individual sub-directories.

How can I configure `git-svn` to achieve this?

Comment: Please don't mark this question as duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn this question is about a situation where all svn branches were contained in a single branch directory, every subdirectory of which is a branch. This is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it with the following `.git/config` file:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = http://server.net:8080/svn/CompanyName
    fetch = ProjectBranch3:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    branches = {ProjectBranch1, ProjectBranch2}:refs/remotes/origin/bracnhes/*
```