# nirvdrum svn2git fetch from interrupted clone

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

I am using the below `svn2git` tool to migrate the repo. I have initiated the clone process and got interrupted due to network connectivity.

```
svn2git svn://repo/repo-name --tags tags --trunk trunk --branches branches --authors "~\authors.txt"
```

https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git

Is there a way to restart the clone process from where it got interrupted?

I have executed the above command again and got the below error message.

In Pro Git, I think we can restart the clone using `git svn fetch`. Is there any similar command in svn2git?

```
Use of uninitialized value in substitution (s///) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Gi
t/SVN.pm line 106.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/lib/perl5/site
_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 106.
```

I am aware that there are other svn2git tools available and may be superior than this tool. I just wanted to resolve this error and go ahead with this tool.

**git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1**

**OS - Windows 7**

**SVN version 1.9.3-SlikSvn**

**svn2git - 2.3.2**

Comment: Git 1.9.5? That looks ancient. try 2.10

Comment: I was initially using git 2. I have got some perl error frequently I.e. every 2-3 hours as I am migrating the large repo nearly 40 gb. So, as suggested in one post, I have moved to git 1.9, 32 bit version.

Comment: btw. you should not use msysgit, but Git for Windows. msysgit is only the development environment to develop Git for Windows, so if you are just a user, you should use Git for Windows instead. I don't know whether this has anything to do with your issue though.