# git fatal: mmap failed: Invalid argument

Tags: git

When i try to issue the command "git status" i get the below message. I am using the command line. Any idea how to fix it please:

```
fatal: mmap failed: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776055/git-for-windows-version-2-5-3-not-able-to-push-changes perhaps?

Comment: @matt Thanks! The solution in this didn't work for me. I have already tried it.

Comment: Oh well, sorry about that. :( All I was able to gather from a search is that it's some kind of git-for-Windows issue, and that things can go wrong with insufficient free space or big repositories. I don't use Windows so I can't actually help.

Comment: I had some large files that I have excluded from my repository.

Comment: Yes, that's what the duplicates do suggest.

Comment: Even after excluding the issue still occur. Any idea what alternative solution i have available.

Answer (score 43):

For me, it was solved by letting OneDrive sync again. It was paused syncing when I got the error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61033756/3718756

Comment: This indeed fixed my similar issue! Thank you for this reply. Weird that OneDrive sync causes this error.

Comment: This issue happens for OneDrive. In my case, this happened when I was in a metered connection.

Comment: For some obscure reason NextCloud (which syncs the repo files to a file server) decided to only keep virtual copies of some of the files (i.e. the local file is zero-sized, and gets downloaded upon access). And at the moment of the git error the file server was offline. Once it got back online I could see the download status and git worked.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was a large ZIP file into the repository (2,33GB).
I resolved moving the ZIP file into a different folder (outside the repo)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to get myself out of this loop when running `git pull` by:

- Fetching `git fetch`
- Checking out a new branch `git checkout -b foo`
- Resetting it to the desired remote branch `git reset --hard origin/master`
- Switching back to the actual local main branch `git checkout -`
- And finally my pull worked `git pull`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a large ISO file into the repository (3,7 GB). One way to push large files to a git repository is to use git-lfs (Git Large File Storage), which is an extension that allows you to store large binary files in a separate storage12.

To use git-lfs, you need to install git-lfs on your machine. Run "git lfs install" once per local repository. Select the large files you want to track with git lfs track '*.iso' (in my case), where iso is the file extension. This will create a .gitattributes file in the root directory of the repo.

Add, commit and push the files as usual with git add, git commit and git push. The large files will be pushed to the git-lfs storage, and only pointers to them will be pushed to the GitHub repository.

For more details, you can check the official documentation of git-lfs here: https://git-lfs.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, I first had to ensure that OneDrive was fully synchronized.  Even after it finished, I still got the `fatal: mmap failed` so then executed this command:

```
git fsck --full
```

Which gave results like:

```
error: unable to mmap .git/objects/02/be056851bfd1dc8fe12de9669b01b9ed97e67e: Invalid argument
error: 02be056851bfd1dc8fe12de9669b01b9ed97e67e: object corrupt or missing: .git/objects/02/be056851bfd1dc8fe12de9669b01b9ed97e67e
error: unable to unpack header of .git/objects/97/13f656021dda35fb21c5a5105e9f96b2fcbc8e
error: 9713f656021dda35fb21c5a5105e9f96b2fcbc8e: object corrupt or missing: .git/objects/97/13f656021dda35fb21c5a5105e9f96b2fcbc8e
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid code lengths set)
error: corrupt loose object 'b60a0147345097f3b94522b7596fedfdd5e7e2fc'
error: unable to unpack contents of .git/objects/b6/0a0147345097f3b94522b7596fedfdd5e7e2fc
error: b60a0147345097f3b94522b7596fedfdd5e7e2fc: object corrupt or missing: .git/objects/b6/0a0147345097f3b94522b7596fedfdd5e7e2fc
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid stored block lengths)
error: corrupt loose object 'e76a5b9a6f4b214963cefb2f107fc1901e24e0f5'
error: unable to unpack contents of .git/objects/e7/6a5b9a6f4b214963cefb2f107fc1901e24e0f5
error: e76a5b9a6f4b214963cefb2f107fc1901e24e0f5: object corrupt or missing: .git/objects/e7/6a5b9a6f4b214963cefb2f107fc1901e24e0f5
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
missing blob 7fc0b6de9d53ef2e18817a21b82cbdfb76b7f8a8
dangling blob e6c2ae0c4509aedad4b6251b7c38cae89b219da3
missing blob 20ca0161417a91bc5978036585e5e421686ec952
...
```

Then I executed these commands to resolve the dangling commits:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

See https://web.archive.org/web/20210116144915/https://tekkie.ro/news/howto-remove-all-dangling-commits-from-your-git-repository/

Be sure that you really want to the items because it will remove all of your stashes, etc.